# Non-greedy RegEx to replace id using JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a solution to replace a substring (id) without brackets before and after it.

Here's my current code, very simple:

```
'deal[ptions_attributes][0][price]'.replace(/\[\d+\]/, '[new_id]'));
result: deal[ptions_attributes][new_id][price]
```

So I don't really wont to use brackets in the new id - '[new_id]' to replace substring with it.
Is there a way to ignore first '[' bracket while replacing and keep clean 'new_id' ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Could you give a before/after example?

Comment: Can't you use capture groups?

Comment: If the _id_ is the only number, sure. If there may be numbers elsewhere then the brackets are the delimiters, so you have to match them to know you're in the right place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes that none of the other strings within `[...]` end with digits

```
/\d+(?=\])/
```

Comment: That is what I've looked for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with lookaround:

```
/(?<=\[)\d+(?=\])/
```

Will match the digits between the brackets, which must be there for the match to succeed, but will not be part of the match.

But as is told in the comments, the lookbehind (`(?<=...)` doesn't work in javascript. So I'm not sure if what you want is possible.

Comment: You can't use look-behind in JavaScript regex

Comment: @garyh.. Yeah, I read sometimes back that look-behind don't work in Javascript, so I assumed that same would be true for look-behind. Strange that one of them work, but not the other.

Comment: @rohit: Lookbehind is a lot harder to implement efficiently. In Python, there's a restriction that it can only be used for constant-length subexpressions, which makes it simple. Allowing variable-length subexpressions makes matching them much slower, so I think they decided this was too problematic and just dropped it entirely.

Comment: @BasWijnen.. Not only in Python. But in Java also, it does not allow for variable length subexpression in look-behind. Don't whether it's for general Regex also or not.

Comment: Seems like look-ahead is enough to solve this. Everytime when I need to use regex I have to relearn it. It's famous- “Now you have two problems”.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.

```
'deal[ptions_attributes][0][price]'.replace(
    /(\[)\d+(\])/,
    function(matchedString,firstCaptureGroup,secondCaptureGroup){
        return firstCaptureGroup + 'new_id' + secondCaptureGroup;
    }
);
```

You're basically capturing the "[" and "]" in capture groups and then putting them back into the output. This ensures that you capture the correct content but doesn't end up forcing you to include the brackets in your output string. You could easily extend this to match any strings before and after the ID you want to replace.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure as to the exact nature of your problem but can you not use :

```
 '[' + 'new_id' + ']'
```

This allows you to use a variable in place of `'new_id'` which may be your intent.